# How to find out the type of field in mongoengine

Tags: django, pymongo, mongoengine

I've been using blinker library to write signals in mongoengine. Where before writing the data to model I'm trying to pre-process the data on certain fieldType. How can I check the type of document field in mongoengine.

```
@classmethod
def pre_save(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
    """
    Pre Save signal
    """
    fields = document._fields
    # If field is of TextField pre-process the data
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct `_fields` is a dict of type `{field_name: FieldClass}` and is what is used internally

The following should help you to get started:

```
@classmethod
def pre_save(cls, sender, document, **kwargs):
    """
    Pre Save signal
    """
    fields = document._fields
    for field_name, field_cls in fields.items():
        if isinstance(field_cls, TextField):
            new_attr_value = ...
            setattr(document, field_name, new_attr_value)
```